# The problem of foldl (with multi level foldl) in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation, fold, foldleft

The foldr version was fast than the foldl version:

the foldr version:

```
cartProdN9 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cartProdN9 xss = 
 foldr h1 [[]] xss where 
  h1 xs yss = foldr g [] xs where
     g x zss = foldr f zss yss where 
         f xs yss = (x:xs):yss
```

The foldl version

```
cartProdN11 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cartProdN11 xss = 
 foldl h1 [[]] xss where 
  h1 yss xs = foldl g [] xs where
     g zss x = foldl f zss yss where 
         f yss xs = (x:xs):yss
```

The process `cartProdN9 [[1,2]| i <- [1 .. 1000]]` is ok . But `cartProdN11 [[1,2]| i <- [1 .. 1000]]` not ok.

The strict version `fold'` is still no ok:

```
foldl' f z []     = z
foldl' f z (x:xs) = let z' = z `f` x 
                       in  z' `seq` foldl' f z' xs
```

Even using the tech in https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/all-about-strictness/

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module D where   
data StrictList a = Cons !a !(StrictList a) | Nil

strictMap :: (a -> b) -> StrictList a -> StrictList b
strictMap _ Nil = Nil
strictMap f (Cons a list) =
  let !b = f a
      !list' = strictMap f list
   in b `seq` list' `seq` Cons b list'

strictEnum :: Int -> Int -> StrictList Int
strictEnum low high =
  go low
  where
    go !x
      | x == high = Cons x Nil
      | otherwise = Cons x (go $! x + 1)

list  :: Int -> StrictList Int
list !x = Cons x (Cons x Nil)

foldlS = \f z l ->
  case l of
    Nil -> z
    Cons !x !xs -> let !z' = z `f` x
                       in  z' `seq` foldlS f z' xs  

listlist :: StrictList (StrictList Int)
listlist = strictMap list $! strictEnum 1 10

cartProdN12 :: StrictList (StrictList a) -> StrictList (StrictList a)
cartProdN12 xss =
 foldlS h1 (Cons Nil Nil) xss where
  h1 !yss !xs = foldlS g Nil xs where
     g !zss !x = foldlS f zss yss where
       f !yss !xs = Cons (Cons x xs ) yss

myhead  :: StrictList a ->  a
myhead =  \l ->
  case l of
    Cons x xs -> x
         
r = cartProdN12 listlist
hr :: Int
hr =  myhead( myhead r)
```

the `listlist = strictMap list $! strictEnum 1 100` still too slow to compute.

So my problem: how to make `foldl` version compute as faster as the `foldr` version? It is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The process cartProdN9 [[1,2]| i <- [1 .. 1000]] is ok .

I sincerely doubt that, because the resulting list will have 2^1000 elements, so you're probably not benchmarking correctly.

Here's a little benchmark I threw together that shows that the simple strict version is actually faster:

```
module Main where

import Test.Tasty.Bench

cartProdN9 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cartProdN9 xss = 
 foldr h1 [[]] xss where 
  h1 xs yss = foldr g [] xs where
     g x zss = foldr f zss yss where 
         f xs yss = (x:xs):yss 

cartProdN11 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cartProdN11 xss = 
 foldl h1 [[]] xss where 
  h1 yss xs = foldl g [] xs where
     g zss x = foldl f zss yss where 
         f yss xs = (x:xs):yss 

mkBench :: ([[Int]] -> [[Int]]) -> Int -> Benchmark
mkBench f n = bench (show n) $ nf f (replicate n [1, 2])

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
  [ bgroup "cartProdN9"  $ map (mkBench cartProdN9) [10,15,20]
  , bgroup "cartProdN11" $ map (mkBench cartProdN11) [10,15,20]
  ]
```

Results:

```
All
  cartProdN9
    10: OK (0.16s)
      36.7 μs ± 3.0 μs
    15: OK (0.29s)
      4.48 ms ± 273 μs
    20: OK (5.75s)
      378  ms ±  28 ms
  cartProdN11
    10: OK (0.28s)
      33.1 μs ± 2.2 μs
    15: OK (0.98s)
      3.76 ms ± 292 μs
    20: OK (5.22s)
      337  ms ±  12 ms
```

The `nf` in the `mkBench` function is very important, if you use `whnf` then you get very different results:

```
All
  cartProdN9
    10: OK (0.14s)
      122  ns ±  11 ns
    15: OK (0.19s)
      189  ns ±  11 ns
    20: OK (0.27s)
      257  ns ±  11 ns
  cartProdN11
    10: OK (0.18s)
      10.7 μs ± 683 ns
    15: OK (0.30s)
      2.41 ms ± 150 μs
    20: OK (0.56s)
      188  ms ± 4.2 ms
```

Comment: I use `haskell for mac`. The foldl one can't stop.  `foldr` version can get one result fast and `haskel for mac` will not continue to compute?

Comment: May be I can change the problem: how to make it compute the first result as fast as foldr?

Comment: The essential difference between laziness and strictness (and also foldr and foldl) is that lazy functions, like foldr, can return a partial result while the computation is still running. Strict functions can only return a result after they have completely finished computing. That is almost the definition of laziness and strictness, there is no way to change that.

Comment: Thanks very much. I need to update my knowledge and tools.

Comment: @jiamo what you could perhaps do is add an extra argument to the strict version which specifies how many results you want to get. Then you can make it so that the function stops whenever that number has been reached. Then you could call for example `cartProdN11 [[1,2]| i <- [1 .. 1000]] 100` to get the first 100 elements of the resulting list. That should be pretty quick to compute.